# Get the building height from the Google MAP API

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, lidar, google-elevation-api

I want to build a website which has a Google MAP which shows a 3D visualization of buildings on it. Is there a way so I can highlights building within a given radius?

Also, I want some information about my chosen point. like

- The height of a building within a radius of the chosen point
- Area of a building within a radius of the chosen point
- All retail within 800 meters walking from the point
- The type of retails logged around the building
- (400-meter) walking distance of existing or planned bus, streetcar, or rideshare stops
- (800-meter) walking distance of existing or planned bus rapid transit stops, light or heavy rail stations, commuter rail stations, or commuter ferry terminals
- The frequency of the found stations for weekdays and weekends
- The trips should be in both directions. No double counting of stations on both sides. Stations within the walking distance allowed counts as one! Projects served by two or more transit routes such that no one route provides more than 60% of the documented levels may earn one additional point, up to the maximum number of points.
- Within 4800 m of biking find a bus rapid transit stop, light or heavy rail station, commuter rail station, or ferry terminal
- Biking is only on bike lanes or roads below 40 km/hr speed limit

Can someone help me with this??